# Does $\ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt n}(1-\cos \frac{1}{\sqrt n})$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to estimate the convergence of:

$$\ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt n}(1-\cos \frac{1}{\sqrt n}) ?$$

I thought of:
$$\ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1-\cos \frac{1}{\sqrt n}}{\sqrt n} $$

And Limit comparison test, however, it wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: I think this is helpful: $1-\cos n=2\sin^2 \dfrac{n}{2}$ and $\sin n<n$ for $n>0$. It can help you compare the limit

Comment: If you know the limit: $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}=\frac12$, you can multiply and divide by ...

Comment: Jean, could you write it down? I can't see it.

Comment: Try $\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(x)$ and $\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}\le1$

Answer (score 2):

$$a_n=\frac{1-\cos(1/\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n}}\sim \frac{1-1+1/(2n)+O(1/n^2)}{\sqrt{n}}\sim \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}+O(1/n^{5/2}).$$ which is convergent

Answer (score 1):

We have $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^*$, $u_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{1}{2n}\frac{2\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}$

As $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{2\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}=1$

We can compare $u_n$ to $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{2n^{3/, 2}}$

We have, $\forall n>0, \frac{1}{2n^{3/, 2}}>0$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)\geq 0$

The quotient tends to 1.

We know that the Riemann series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ is convergent (3/2>1) so  $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2n^{3/2}}$ is convergent.

By comparison theorem, $\sum_{n\geq 1} u_n$ is convergent.